# Writing the Cauchy Integral Formula for functions

Tags: complex-analysis

In my text it says that:

The Cauchy integral forumla for $f(z) = z^2$ yields

$$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{z^2}{z-1}\,dz = 2\pi iz^2 |_{z=1} = 2\pi i$$

1. Why is $|z| =2$ the path of the integral?
2. Where does the $1$ come from in the denominator $z-1$?

It further states for example that the Cauchy integral formula for the second derivative of $z^2\sin z$ yields:

$$\oint_{|z|=2\pi} \frac{z^2\sin z}{(z-\pi)^3}dz$$ How do we acquire this integral?

Comment: It might help you to write down the formula being used to see how it applies to these cases. The integrals are probably being made up as examples, then the formula is used to evaluate them, showing you how to use the formula in particular cases.

Comment: $f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial{D}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw$

Answer (score 2):

$|z|=2$ just means the circle of radius $2$ around the origin. It is chosen as the path because you are trying to find the value of $f(z)$ at $z=1$, and $|\zeta|=2$ is a circle containing $1$ on its interior with $f(\zeta) = \zeta^2$ holomorphic in an open set containing the disk whose boundary is the circle. By the Cauchy integral formula $f(z)$ is
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\zeta|=2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta.
$$
Put in $z=1$:
$$
1 = 1^2 = f(1) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{\zeta^2}{\zeta-1}d\zeta.
$$
The second formula is just Cauchy's differentiation formula applied to $g(z) = z^2\sin z$ at $\pi$. To obtain it without the theorem, Taylor expand $z^2\sin z$ around $\pi$, note that you can get $f^{(2)}(\pi)$ from the coefficients of the Taylor series, and play around.